# Trying to write a program that ask the user to input parentheses and brackets. The program will then tell the users whether they are properly nested

Tags: c, compiler-errors, undefined, parentheses, brackets

As the title states I am trying to write a program that will tell the user if there inputted brackets and or parentheses are properly nested. Here is my code.

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define STACK_SIZE 100

char contents[STACK_SIZE];
int top = 0;

void stack_overflow();
void stack_underflow();

void make_empty(void)
{
    top = 0;
}
bool is_empty(void)
{
    return top == 0;
}

bool is_full (void)
{
    return top == STACK_SIZE;
}

void push(char i)
{
    if (is_full())
        stack_overflow();
    else
        contents[top++] = i;
}

char pop(void)
{
   if (is_empty())
        stack_underflow();
    else
       return contents[--top]; 
}





int main(void)
{
    char input;
    bool is_nested=true;
    printf("Enter parentheses and/or braces: ");

    while ((input = getchar()) != '\n')
    {
        if(input =='(' || input == '{')
            push(input);
        if(input ==')' && pop() != '(')
            is_nested = false;
        if(input =='}' && pop() != '{')
            is_nested = false;
    }   
    if (is_empty() == false) is_nested = false;

    if (is_nested)
        printf("Parentheses/braces are nested properly");
    else
        printf("Parentheses/braces are not nested properly");

    return 0;
}
```

When I compile the code I keep getting the error:

C:\Users\g\AppData\Local\Temp\ccy6YhqI.o:brackets.c:(.text+0x45): undefined reference to `stack_overflow'

C:\Users\g\AppData\Local\Temp\ccy6YhqI.o:brackets.c:(.text+0x76): undefined reference to `stack_underflow'

collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

I cannot seem to find why I am getting this error. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `void stack_overflow();` is a declaration, not a definition. To make a definition you need `void stack_overflow(void) { /*some code*/ }`. The error is telling you the compiler (actually the linker part of the compiler) cannot find the definition of the function. Definitions also serve as prototypes / declarations.

Answer (score 0):

clearly you haven't implemented stack_overflow() nor stack_underflow().

void foo(); is not a sufficient function definition.